# RoR put image_path in data attribute using HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I starded to use HAML and I ran into a problem.

I need to put the `image_path()` url in an elements `data-attribute`.

Let's say that my image is `app/assets/images/foo/bar/image.png`.

I figured out how to get the `image_path`, for example

```
%h1 #{image_path ("foo/bar/image.png")}
/ will return
```

> /assets/foo/bar/image-944cf331269515d31d4ab23897df6c217e4593a942af756d4433a4987961cc29.png

Which is good. Now I want to put this string into an element's data attribute, for example on `h1`.

This is what I'd tried:

```
%h1{data: {'foo' => #{image_path ("foo/bar/image.png")} }}
/ returns an error
%h1{data: {'foo' => '#{image_path ("foo/bar/image.png")}' }}
/ returns
/ <h1 data-foo="#{image_path ('foo/bar/image.png')}"></h1>
```

This is what I'm looking for:

```
<h1 data-foo="/assets/foo/bar/image-944cf331269515d31d4ab23897df6c217e4593a942af756d4433a4987961cc29.png"></h1>
```

What is the right way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youre almost close, but maybe you dont know the difference of 'string' and "string".

In Ruby a string with 'string' wont replace anything. You need to call a string with "string" and you can use inside #{} to use ruby code in that string

test the following in your console

```
"#{1+1}" # outputs "2"
'#{1+1}' # outputs "#{1+1}"
```

**now back to your problem:**

```
%h1{data: {'foo' => '#{image_path ("foo/bar/image.png")}' }}
change to
%h1{data: {'foo' => "#{image_path ('foo/bar/image.png')}" }}
```

but you dont need those string manipulation, you can go straight for

```
%h1{data: {'foo' => image_path ("foo/bar/image.png") }}
```

or if you use ruby 2.2.1 you can go even more straight

```
%h1{data: {"foo": image_path ("foo/bar/image.png") }}
```

or to keep it totally short and more readable

```
%h1{"data-foo": image_path ("foo/bar/image.png")}
```

**In Ruby 2.2.1 the behavior of hashes changed a little**

```
2.1.2 :008 >   {"foo": "bar"}
SyntaxError: (irb):8: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting => {"foo": "bar"}
   ^

2.2.1 :003 >   {"foo": "bar"}
 => {:foo=>"bar"}
```

thats the reason why the last 2 options i suggested are only working in 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

```
%h1{data: {'foo' => image_path("foo/bar/image.png") }}
```